# Immediately after installing Webpacker in Rails 5.2.1, I get a `can't modify frozen Array` error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I started a new project and am more or less a junior developer. Everything was going fine setting up Rails with a Postgres database, set up a model/controller/view to generate Redcarpet Markdown, set up Rspec/Capybara tests, etc.

I wind up with a Gemfile like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

# Language version
ruby '2.5.1'

# Framework version
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'

# Database
gem 'pg'

# Database administration
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.3'

# Styling
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

# Scripting
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 3.5'

# Performance improvements
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

# Markdown parsing
gem 'redcarpet'

# JSON API builder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

# Make it work on Windows
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' in the code to get a debugger console.
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]

  # Testing
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end

group :development do
  # Call 'console' in the code to get a live console.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'

  # Performance improvements for development
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Testing
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
```

And follow the Webpacker docs to install Webpack to use ES6 in my project:

```
bundle
bundle exec rails webpacker:install
```

It installs fine, but now when I try to run `bundle exec rails s`, without changing any other file, I get a long stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    69: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    68: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    67: from /Users/danrice/Software/Novum-Opus-Projects/Novum_Opus/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    66: from /Users/danrice/Software/Novum-Opus-Projects/Novum_Opus/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    65: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    64: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    63: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    62: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    61: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    60: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    59: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    58: from /Users/danrice/Software/Novum-Opus-Projects/Novum_Opus/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    57: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
    56: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
    55: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
    54: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    53: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    52: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    51: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    50: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    49: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    48: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    47: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    46: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    45: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    44: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    43: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    42: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    41: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    40: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
    39: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
    38: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    37: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
    36: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    35: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    34: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    33: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    32: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    31: from config.ru:in `<main>'
    30: from config.ru:in `new'
    29: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    28: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    27: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    26: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require_relative'
    25: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
    24: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
    23: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
    22: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    21: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    20: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    19: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    18: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    17: from /Users/danrice/Software/Novum-Opus-Projects/Novum_Opus/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    16: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    15: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    14: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    13: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    12: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    11: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    10: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
     9: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
     8: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
     7: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
     6: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
     5: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
     4: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
     3: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
     2: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/webpacker-3.5.5/lib/webpacker/railtie.rb:51:in `block in <class:Engine>'
     1: from /Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:76:in `insert'
/Users/danrice/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:76:in `insert': can't modify frozen Array (FrozenError)
```

Anyone have any theories on what in the world is happening? Thanks so much!

Commenters asked for my `config/environment.rb` file, which is this:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

Comment: Can you please upload this fine `config/environment.rb`

Comment: Something you did -> `17: from /Users/danrice/Software/Novum-Opus-Projects/Novum_Opus/config/environment.rb:5:in '<main>'`

Comment: Sure. Added it to the post above.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the project is extremely new. I'd recommend rolling a new one and starting with Webpacker to see if you have the same issue. If you don't then it probably wasn't Webpacker causing this problem.

If this is the case, then be mindful to commit every change you make, especially any Gemfile, config, or initializer changes, and that way you can rollback easily to before the initialization problem occurs and better debug.

I have sometimes had success stopping the spring server:

`spring stop`

before running `rails s` again when getting an initialization problem like this. But if that works, then a hard reboot of your system would have cleared it, too.

Comment: I will try `spring stop`. The project is pretty recent, that's true, so I may just start over with Webpacker from the get-go- I tried putting Webpacker in a fresh Rails 5.2.1 install and it worked.

I'll leave the question open in case someone else has run across this though. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem may be in webpacker gem. Please see the PR at github: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1700

Shortly, people say that eror is risen in a secondary queue after a some primary error, in case when webpacker is trying adding devServer middleware.

In my case I just pill out the explicit requiring the rails environment files from the test helper initializes.